# NamedParameterJdbcTemplate and composite key

Tags: java, spring-data, jdbctemplate, named-parameters

I've written a method to retrieve a list of entries with NamedParameterJdbcTemplate:

```
public final Map<K,V> findAll(final Collection<K> keys) {
    if (keys == null) {
        return null;
    }
    MapSqlParameterSource parameters = new MapSqlParameterSource();
    parameters.addValue("ids", keys);
    List<V> values = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(datasource).query("select * from TABLE where id in ( :ids )", parameters, mapper);          

    Map<K,V> results = new HashMap<K, V>();
    for (V v : values) {
        results.put((K) v.getId(), v);              
    }        
    return results;
}
```

but this works only if the key are simple type.
I cannot make it work with a primary key like:

```
public class CompositeKey implements Serializable {

    private long field1;
    private long field2;
}
```

how can I make work my findAll() method with composite keys?

Comment: You didn't ask any question.

Comment: This is not a question about Java nor Spring JDBC. This is about general SQL syntax and tuple comparison. Please update your question and include the type of the DB you are using.

Comment: On the other hand - you will have issues constructing the query with `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate`... so both aspects of the questions are valid. But you need to know how the SQL query you want to construct should look like.

Comment: My question is not about SQL. The instruction `:ids` is only valid for NamedParameterJdbcTemplate and I want to know how handle composite primary keys. There's nothing to do with SQL.

Answer (score 10):

Your question should be answered in parts:

- how to write `SELECT` with combining `IN` and tuple comparison
- how to write such `SELECT` using `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate`

## How to query multiple objects with compund PK

PostgreSQL / MySQL (probably Oracle as well):

```
 SELECT * FROM foo WHERE (field1, field2) IN ((1, 1), (1, 3));
```

SQL Server (a bit of a hack; works in PostgreSQL as well):

```
SELECT * FROM foo 
INNER JOIN (VALUES (1, 1), (1, 3)) AS _CONDITION(field1, field2) ON
        foo.field1 = _CONDITION.field1 AND foo.field2 = _CONDITION.field2;
```

## How to make the query using NamedParameterJdbcTemplate

Use `List<Object[]>` as your parameter type. See [JavaDoc for NamedParameterUtils](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.5.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/namedparam/NamedParameterUtils.html#substituteNamedParameters%28org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.ParsedSql,%20org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.SqlParameterSource%29) or the [official documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/jdbc.html#jdbc-in-clause) on this topic.

### Example using map parameters

```
public List<MyObject> findByIds(Collection<MyKey> keys) {
    List<Object[]> keyTuples = new ArrayList<Object[]>(keys.size());
    for (MyKey key : keys) {
        keyTuples.add(new Object[] { key.getField1(), key.getField2() });
    }
    jdbcTemplate.query("SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE (field1, field2) IN (:keys)", 
            Collections.singletonMap("keys", keyTuples), new MyObjectRowMapper());
}
```

Comment: @pavel-coral thanks. this is surely the right answer, anyway I cannot clearly understand how to translate your explanation in code. I defined a sql string like `select * from TABLE where (field1, field2) in (:field1, :field2)` then if I execute the method `BeanPropertySqlParameterSource parameters = new BeanPropertySqlParameterSource(key); String sql = NamedParameterUtils.substituteNamedParameters(sql, parameters);` and I got the sql `select * from TABLE where (field1, field2) in (?, ?)`. Now I'm stuck translating the collection of compound keys `Collecion<K> keys`.

Comment: @patrizio.munzi I've added simple example using single map parameter. The way in your own answer is a bit complicated.

Comment: Btw. if you really want to use reflection, then use Spring's `BeanWrapperImpl`. But I would recommend rather using interfaces (e.g. implement `Object[] getTuples()` method on some `CompoundKey` interface) or common *entity* / *key* superclass instead of using generic methods / types.

Comment: What happens if keyTuples is an empty list? Will this work? If no, is there a elegant solution to this instead of having two separate queries or writing a ternary condition and manipulating the query string?

Answer (score 0):

I had to use a workaround I'm not completely happy with but it works.
I had to manually translate the list of beans in a list array objects and then pass the list of array objects to the NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.

If anyone out there has a more elegant solution, please share it with me.

## Final findAll method implementation

```
    public final Map<K,V> findAll(final Collection<K> keys) throws DaoMethodNotSupportedException {

    List<Object[]> keyObjsList = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
    ParsedSql parsedSql = NamedParameterUtils.parseSqlStatement(":field1 :field2");
    for (K key : keys) {
        SqlParameterSource paramSource = new BeanPropertySqlParameterSource(key);
        Object[] keyParams = NamedParameterUtils.buildValueArray(parsedSql, paramSource, null);
        keyObjsList.add(keyParams);
    }

    MapSqlParameterSource parameters = new MapSqlParameterSource();
    parameters.addValue("primaryKeys", keyObjsList);

    List<V> values = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(datasource).query("select * from TABLE where (field1, field2) in ( :primaryKeys )", parameters, valueMapper);          

    for (V v : values) {
        results.put((K) v.getPrimaryKey(), v);
    }        
    return results;
}
```

Thanks to everyone